# What might cause this ('True', 'buy') error? django-paypal

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

Im new to django-paypal and im trying to figure out how to run it. But this is error is preventing me to continue. What have I overlooked? My view code simply are copypasted in the documentation of django paypal.

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:
>   Django Version: 1.6
>   Exception Type: KeyError
>   Exception Value:
>   ('True', 'buy')
>   Exception Location: /home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/standard/forms.py in get_image, line 143
>   Python Executable:  /home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.6
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home/kevcal/channelfix/resources/paypalshit',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
>    '/home/kevcal/.virtualenvs/paypalshit/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Mon, 22 Dec 2014 15:20:02 +0000

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response


from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

def view_that_asks_for_money(request):

    # What you want the button to do.
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": "10000000.00",
        "item_name": "name of the item",
        "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
        "return_url": "https://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
        "cancel_return": "https://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",

    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render_to_response("paypal.html", context)
```

paypal.html

```
<h1>Show me the money!</h1>
<!-- writes out the form tag automatically -->
{{ form.render }}
```

Comment: Show us the code of get_image, line 143

Comment: the thing is that, i think it is handled by 'PayPalPaymentsForm'. Look whats before get_image. Sorry im really new to django-paypal.

Comment: Wow.. this was last modified 6 years ago. Please use a more actively used library. Moreover, you might want to check the master branch instead of the dev (which looks more stable).

Comment: Sure? i never thought about that. I used pip install django-paypal.